# Keras 'accuracy' metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am aware that when calling 'accuracy' in keras model, the actual function that gets picked depends on the choice of the loss. However I am having difficulties understanding what exactly is going on in my case:

```
model_base.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(), 'acc', 'accuracy'])
```

(out of paranoia, I am running both 'acc' and 'accuracy')

Since my loss is binary cross-entropy, i'd assume that keras should choose binary accuracy, but if i run the model above, i see differences. Here is a snippet:

```
Epoch 5/5
230/230 [==============================] - 8s 34ms/step - loss: 0.2783 - binary_accuracy: 0.8984 - acc: 0.9005 - accuracy: 0.9005 - val_loss: 0.1671 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8995 - val_acc: 0.9355 - val_accuracy: 0.9355
```

Why is there such a difference?